# Column names using Oracle reserved word

Tags: sql, oracle, identifier, firedac

Inside my database I have some tables that use a column with a reserved word name for example user, I have created it using " as "USER" but when I want to get it I have realized that I have to put it in capital letters, I have already investigated and I obtained that when placing " oracle respects it as case sensitive, they somehow know how to avoid this and obtain my column without the need for it to be written as defined, that is, case insensitive.
I am working Oracle with Firedac, on the Firedac side, do you know if something can be done so that this can be solved by having to put the column name as it is?

Comment: Don't compound the problem by writing even more bad code just to "make it work". Sooner or later you will have no choice but to do the right thing - which is to change the column name, and find all the queries where you used the bad name and fix them too. The more you delay this step, the harder it will get, and it **will** happen sooner or later, no matter what you think.

Answer (score 3):

No.

You chose to have a column that conflicts with a reserved word, so you had to quote it when you declared it. You also need to quote this identifier everytime you use it - and a quoted identifier is case-sensitive by design.

I would strongly suggest avoiding having column names that conflict with SQL reserved word (or keywords). There is no benefit, and many drawbacks. You could just rename that column to `usr`, `username`, `userid`, or else. Declare the new name as a unquoted identifier, and you will never need to worry about this all afterwards.